# Encrypt a String with a given RSA public key OpenSSL

Tags: encryption, openssl, cryptography, rsa

I am needing to encrypt this hash using the RSA algorithm with the following public key

Hash

`af7c19d5b0b58568e77ccb4ca7530ca1a68d087e11911ff7ac4899ef3e177aff`

Public Key

```
 -----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIICIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAg8AMIICCgKCAgEAqTqckpLgyBqa53dv5MgW
qwYu0toPqdZc5+46IYsaB1GsAiVniW/6hnnITemI1VRybTO5zSyBpeRmo3KnImbr
3nD/xMi8VhcVcsa1GGRuoYRET+h5xbwuzYUryp04sFn47faV2TIuFvnsIkNnuY1K
r73DnnnXeglyN+obVoj5wZ8z8HH45Dk2CcHJpy9UM6zw0s4H2vutbAyxP2gaNZkO
YUUdxfoQ9/xXgce1TDpgairrOKC7t6drQQF3S32KZeV8hZiV+TZGyjXuuviqXU7m
+0WUYXwP49yZnIWizSu5Zojv/U1ip2ZxmJXBlhPAtFvND3uiKBcoxDr0tzluznjF
wCU6CFvYsboFksUAXZkvN4RwFjo82DpHpm9qYgGS82LQJpyhGP+EiTNLKIUNk7+V
778p9sweRI39Hrs3vhxfkNF8QjxkRFyxcz/THjHTJhKvjU4FycpEgDnBqWnk9OpO
S1ZvFblPSv+LT2NvfPb0n1BpcdJycf6C7RKG/307dBjKHHJxItCWZ6FrmKW7/Kvn
NHxPzXfTDMX/F4dEOYAjFl/WUpQFx7SN4PaNiYNWlTBd2aJQd7VdJytc/a3/KGta
1kgUuSlLN5UR4lgTPZchqhSE1UwOfpG1f8rpZ5N8lf/EWO3R5gy2Zo48eBdfkBZ5
R9VhZ2QIZJ1xpJYfmmjp0T8CAwEAAQ==
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

Ive attempted to use OpenSSL, but continue to be told "cannot load public key"

Is there another way?

Comment: Show the command you used to invoke OpenSSL and the exact output you got.

Comment: openssl rsautl -encrypt -inkey public_key.pem -pubin -in encrypt.txt -out encrypted.txt
unable to load Public Key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an extra space at the start of your public key, right before `---- BEGIN`.

Remove that, and it works.

Comment: Worked a treat, feel like an idiot! thank you!